# How to pthread_barrier_destroy() without waiting for pthread_barrier_wait()

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a multithreaded application that uses barriers to synchronise worker threads.

At the end of function compute(), threads are cancelled:

```
...
for(int i=0;i<p; i++){
        printf("Thread %lu completed in %d passes\n",threads[i],find_tstat(threads[i])->count);
        pthread_cancel(threads[i]);
    }
    printf("================================================================\n");   
    return a;
```

Threads are interrupted in the middle of computation, so they may be in between barriers. This is likely what's causing pthread_barrier_destroy() to hang, is because some barrier_wait() has not returned yet.

The question is; how can I still destroy even if a wait() hasn't returned?

Comment: You have to show us how `compute` is implemented and btw. where do you create your threads, what is/are your thread starting function(s) and how and where do you use `pthread_barrier_wait`. In short, you have to provide more code.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük I can tell you that the reason that destroy() is hanging is because, at some point, threads will be destroyed before all synchronizing on a pthread_barrier_wait(). So, the question is, how can I still destroy even if a wait() hasn't returned?

Comment: I have changed the question to reflect this

Comment: Using `pthread_cancel()` is a bad idea in general. Better to have a way to notify a thread that it should cleanly stop. Setting an atomic variable that the thread periodically checks, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to your question is: you can't.

1. [man pthread_barrier_destroy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_destroy)

> The results are undefined if pthread_barrier_destroy() is called when any thread is blocked on the barrier

2. [man pthread_cancel](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cancel)

> On Linux, cancellation is implemented using signals.

3. [man pthread_barrier_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_wait)

> If a signal is delivered to a thread blocked on a barrier, upon return from the signal handler the thread shall resume waiting at the barrier if the barrier wait has not completed (that is, if the required number of threads have not arrived at the barrier during the execution of the signal handler); otherwise, the thread shall continue as normal from the completed barrier wait. Until the thread in the signal handler returns from it, it is unspecified whether other threads may proceed past the barrier once they have all reached it.
>
> A thread that has blocked on a barrier shall not prevent any unblocked thread that is eligible to use the same processing resources from eventually making forward progress in its execution. Eligibility for processing resources shall be determined by the scheduling policy.

Comment: ... so don't let any thread wait at a pthreads barrier if you're not *sure* that you want to let enough threads reach the barrier to let them all pass through.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, yes, but that is a design choice. The main statement here is, you cannot destroy a barrier if any threads are blocked on that barrier without risking undefined behaviour. And the OP wants to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is posed:

> The question is; how can I still destroy even if a wait() hasn't returned?

the answer is "you can't", as [your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69934346/2402272) explains.

However, with good enough record keeping, you can launch just enough extra threads specifically to wait at the barrier in order to let any other threads already waiting pass through.  This would likely be tied together with code and data intended to provide for your threads to be shut down cleanly instead of being canceled, which is also something you should do.

On the other hand, it's pretty easy to roll your own barrier with use of a condition variable and mutex, and the result is more flexible.  You still should not be canceling threads, but you can make waits at a hand-rolled barrier such as I describe soft-cancelable.  This would be my recommendation.